# div visibility by java script not working

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

I have a form in which I have kept two fields in a div. There is a check box that determines the visibility of this div MY code is not working.It is not allowing  me to click on this

```html
<script>    
  function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    }
</script>

<input type="CHECKBOX" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="period" id="yesCheck"> 
<label for "period" style="padding-left:20px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Time </label>    

<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden" >
  <label style="padding:0px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Date From </label>
  <input style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" type="date" id="datefrom" name="datefrom"value="" placeholder="Date from" >
  <label style="padding:0px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">To</label>
  <input style="padding:0px;margin:0px;"type="date"  id="dateto" name="dateto"  value="" placeholder="Date to">
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work actually: https://jsfiddle.net/ek70xbaf/1/

Comment: @Paflow but is is not working in my webpage

Comment: Are you trying to click on the "Time" label?

Comment: not working at all

Comment: @roopa what errors do you see in the console on your webpage?

Comment: If it works here, but not on your page, then by definition we can't see the cause of the problem. Please include any error and if possible, any other code that may be involved in the problem.

Comment: @It is not allowing me to click on the checkbox

Comment: What are you trying? When you click on the checkbox, the div toggles. If this does not work, you habe maybe some problems with your browser or such.

Comment: i think i have an issue with js cdn

Comment: is there any issue with js CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` attribute in the `label` accepts the element `id`, not the `name`

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

```html
<input id="yesCheck" type="CHECKBOX" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="period">
<label for="yesCheck" style="padding-left:20px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Time </label>
<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
  <label style="padding:0px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Date From </label>
  <input style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" type="date" id="datefrom" name="datefrom" value="" placeholder="Date from">
  <label style="padding:0px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">To</label>
  <input style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" type="date" id="dateto" name="dateto" value="" placeholder="Date to">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed id for input tag. `id="yesCheck"`

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

```html
<input id="yesCheck" type="CHECKBOX" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="period">
<label for "period" style="padding-left:20px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Time </label>
<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
  <label style="padding:0px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Date From </label>
  <input style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" type="date" id="datefrom" name="datefrom" value="" placeholder="Date from">
  <label style="padding:0px;margin:0px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">To</label>
  <input style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" type="date" id="dateto" name="dateto" value="" placeholder="Date to">
</div>
```